# Multiple queries returning incorrect result

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am using parse to try and create an instagram style app where users can follow other users. The below code tries to query my parse database and check if the user who is logged in 'follows' another user. It currently enters where you can see "ENTERS HERE BUT DOES NOT APPEND". Two issues: 
1. It is entering this location for all users, not just the ones that the currently logged in user follows
2. the append.isfollowing is not working. Initially, isfollowing.count is 0, and when i print it at the end again, it remains 0. Even though it enters the if statement that it is contained in, the append does not work
Code below - Thanks!

```
var usernames = [""]
var userids = [""]
var isFollowing = [Bool]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    var query = PFUser.query()
    query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

        //check if we have any objects
        if let users = objects {

            //for each element in the users array
            for object in users {

                //convert to PFuser
                if let user = object as? PFUser {

                        //check if the current user is following each user. if so update isfollowing array
                        var query = PFQuery(className: "followers")

                        query.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)
                        query.whereKey("following", equalTo: user.objectId!)


                        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in
                            //if objects returns something
                            if let objects = objects {

                                //if we enter here we know that the logged in user is following the curr user. Update the isfollowing array
                                //ENTERS HERE BUT DOES NOT APPEND
                                self.isFollowing.append(true)

                            } else {
                                self.isFollowing.append(false)
                            }
                        })   
                }
            }
        }
        //reload the table data
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })

        print(self.isFollowing.count)
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1. It is entering this location for all users, not just the ones that the currently logged in

The condition being tested by the inner query, `if let objects = objects` tests if the array is defined (non-nil).  What you want is to test if the array is non-nil and non-empty, like:

```
if objects?.count > 0 {  // we found at least one
```

> 2. the append.isfollowing is not working

The code that appends to `isFollowing` runs asynchronously.  The print statement at the end of viewDidLoad runs right away, *before* the queries have completed.  That's why it appears not to work (it just hasn't worked *yet*).